# REST API, POST Rich Text Item to Domino server

Tags: rest, post, lotus-domino

i am trying to use the REST-API of my domino lotus notes server (9.0.1FP8)

It works for simple text-fields but if I try to add an rich-text-item as json, the domino server receives only the text-fields and the richt-text field is empty.

I try it with Postman and a Postrequest to http://localhost/Test/JSON_Vie…s/name/List?form=mainForm, 
where I send the json

```
{
    "title":"test rich text",
    "artist":"rich texter",
    "ntracks":1,
    "attachments": {
        "type": "multipart",
        "content": [
            {
                "contentType": "multipart/alternative; Boundary=\"0__=4EBB0925DFBB40F18f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0925DFBB40F1\"",
                "contentDisposition": "inline"
            },
            {
                "contentType": "text/plain; charset=US-ASCII",
                "data": "test rich text",
                "boundary": "--0__=4EBB0925DFBB40F18f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0925DFBB40F1"
            },
            {
                "contentType": "text/html; charset=US-ASCII",
                "contentDisposition": "inline",
                "data": "<html><body><font size=\"2\" face=\"sans-serif\"><b>test rich text</b></font></body></html>",
                "boundary": "--0__=4EBB0925DFBB40F18f9e8a93df938690918c4EBB0925DFBB40F1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The mask mainForm has the text-fields "title", "artist" , "ntracks" and the rich text-field "attachments".

How can I send an image as json and what is "boundary"?

Have you any idea , what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you using DAS or ExtLib?

Comment: Have you tried something simple like this? "attachments":{"contentType":"text/html", "data":"<b>test rich text</b>", "type":"richtext"}

Comment: @ThomasAdrian: I just want to test it for simple html code firt. But actual I want to send an image per json, and I don't get how to do that. I use DAS.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I tried your simple json for attachments but the field is still empty.

Comment: Try with a PUT instead of POST (https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp%3FlookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Document_PUT_dds10&content=apicontent)

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: this is really interesting. If I use put on an existing document and add my attachment field in the json, it works!  Is it somehow possible in a POST?

Comment: I will add that as an answer then that you can accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation from IBM](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp%3FlookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Document_PUT_dds10&content=apicontent) you need to use PUT (instead of POST) in order to update the fields.

Comment: Here again: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Document_Collection_POST_dds10&content=apicontent
there is an example to add an attachment to a POST-Request.

SO why it works only for existing documents per PUT?

Comment: I guess the documentation could be clearer, but it's working as designed. To create a new document, you POST to the document collection resource (no UNID in the URL).  To update an existing document, you PUT to the document resource (with an UNID in the URL).  This distinction between PUT and POST is consistent with REST best practices.

Comment: Yes, @Dave Delay I understand the difference between POST and PUT. But I don't understand why i can't create(Post) a single document with an attachment.

So I have to make a POST request first for the text-fields and afterwards I have to make a PUT just for adding the attachment?

Comment: I don't see an attachment in your original post. There are just three parts (multipart/alternative, text/plain & text/html). With the right input, you can definitely create an attachment in a POST request. Since you have already accepted this answer, perhaps you should create another question about the attachment.

Comment: @DaveDelay : it's correct, i firstly try to post simple html code for the rich text field "attachments" to ensure that this works! But it doesn't.

My POST-Request for an image as attachment looks like that <code>{
   "title":"bild",
   "artist":"bild",
   "attachments":{
      "type":"multipart",
      "content":[
         {
            "contentType":"image/png",           "data":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARwAAADJCAIAAAB+EhqfAAAAAXNSR...",
            "contentTransferEncoding":"base64"
         }
      ]
   }
} </code>

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting a little bit, I now know what was wrong. If I do the POST on the address `http://localhost/Test/JSON_Views.nsf/api/data/documents?form=mainForm` it works with the attachment. If I use `http://localhost/Test/JSON_Views.nsf/api/data/collections/name/List?form=mainForm&computewithform=true` the attachment field is ignored. But maybe you can explain me, what the extra field boundary is and if I can set the contentLocation by the name of my attachment?

Comment: Based on your comments, it seems like you were able to POST a document with an attachment.  That's good.  If you have a follow up question, I recommend starting a new thread.  StackOverflow works best when a question is as narrow as possible and each question has a clear answer.  Using answers to ask follow up questions is confusing.